# How to work with a proxy in Firefox with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, ubuntu, firefox, watir

I have code with the Chrome browser and this works, but I never worked with Firefox, but an Ubuntu server normally works only with Firefox, and now I have a question: How can I work with a proxy on the Firefox browser using the proxy_chain_rb gem?

I think my code for the Chrome browser will work in Firefox if you tell me how I can make Firefox options. My problem - I don’t know how I can use Firefox options and manuals are old. How can I replace my code for Google in Firefox?

#### Code

```
    require 'watir'
    require 'proxy_chain_rb'
    require 'selenium-webdriver'

    time2 = Time.now
    file = File.new("report.json", "a:UTF-8")
    myuseragent = File.readlines("user_agents.txt").sample
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_emulation(user_agent: (myuseragent))
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    puts "Work started: " + time2.inspect
    u_proxy = File.readlines("proxy.txt").sample
    real_proxy        =   u_proxy
    server            =   ProxyChainRb::Server.new
    generated_proxy   =   server.start(real_proxy)


    proxy = {
        http: generated_proxy,
        ssl:  generated_proxy
    }

    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(:proxy => proxy)
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps, options: options
    driver.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent')
    driver.get "https://raskruty.ru/"
```

Comment: You will not have answer here unless you include WATIR or cabypara. Should I add watir tag?

Comment: ok, should this